# How to install yarn to fix the dependency issue in the local repo?

Tags: javascript, github, blockchain, yarnpkg

I hope my question doesn't sound too silly.

I'm trying to install Yarn on Git Hub.I'm trying to make a relayer on the Dharma Protocol. First, I cloned the repo to my workstation. The next step was to "install the dependencies: yarn". The issue is I'm not sure if I'm meant to input this into my laptop terminal or somewhere on the GitHub Desktop workstation?

The next step would have been to launch the blockchain via `yarn blockchain`. I'm of the notion I would have to use visual studio for all of this.

Any direction would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: When you say `trying to install yarn on GitHub`, what do you mean? Getting the yarn package manager to run on the GitHub server?

Comment: Can you share the link from which you are reading the instructions?

Comment: @LloydFrancis This is the link https://github.com/dharmaprotocol/relayer-kit . Thank you.

Comment: @LloydFrancis I installed Git Hub for my desktop. I followed the instructions in the link which required me to clone the repo. I successfully did that. My issue now is that the next instruction was to install dependencies in order to run the project.I'm not sure whether I'm meant to open visual studio code or my terminal and then try to install yarn or if I can do this through the GitHub Desktop work space?

Comment: That would be your terminal.

Comment: I helped to change the title, `trying to install yarn on GitHub` is too weired

Answer (score 0):

When you clone the repository using GitHub Desktop, it creates a directory. Navigate there using terminal and just type `yarn` and press [enter].

Your steps may vary depends on which system you are, but most of the times starting either Terminal or Command Prompt should do the trick.

It may be that your system lacks yarn, since it is not bundled with any system that I know about. If so, please refer to their docs: https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it now!